# Asterisk and DAHDI setup

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk, pbx

I have an issue with an asterisk server I'm trying to install. I have an Amazon server , `Ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit`. I have followed the instructions from [install-asterisk-1-8-from-source-on-ubuntu-12-04](http://www.kartook.com/2012/08/install-asterisk-1-8-from-source-on-ubuntu-12-04/) step by step. I get to the part where I download DAHDI folder and try the `"make"` command but get the following error which I posted in the bottom. I'm not a Linux genius but what I have understood and tried to solve is. I don't have the source for the kernel I have in my box but I don't know how to get them or how to change them so that DAHDI can work. Can anyone please help?

> /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.6.1+2.6.1# make make -C linux all
>   make[ 1]: Entering directory
>   `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.6.1+2.6.1/linux' make -C
>   drivers/dahdi/firmware firmware-loaders make[2]: Entering directory`
>   /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.6.1+2.6.1/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
>   make[ 2]: Leaving directory
>   `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.6.1+2.6.1/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
>   You do not appear to have the sources for the 3.2.0-31-virtual kernel
>   installed. make[ 1]: *** [modules]
>
> Error 1 make[ 1]: Leaving directory
>   `/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.6.1+2.6.1/linux' make: *** [all]
>
> Error 2
>   root@domU-12-31-39-03-20-24:/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.6.1+2.6.1#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to also install the kernel sources to resolve dependencies.

Try running this, and then re-run make.

```
apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Comment: Tried it and still get the same error. When I ran that command it added linux-source-3.2.0.tar.bz2 which I'm guessing it extracted linux-source-3.2.0 from it to the same directory. Inside of it file I found Debian and Debian.Master and linux-source-3.2.0.tar.bz2 in there as well. When I ran that command it should have compiled as well right? Or do I have somehow have to go into one of those directories and compile it myself or something. Even though I have been trying to maybe I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: When you ran **apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`** what result did you get?